# PHP MySQL if latest timestamp is two weeks older than today then

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp

I'm trying to query a table where attendance records are kept per user and group.  If the lastest timestamp per user and group is two weeks older than today's date, then an image will show.  Here is the code I have at this point but I don't think I'm understanding the time formats or something.

```
$tsquery = mysql_query("SELECT ts FROM `attendance` WHERE contact_id='$contactid' AND             group_id='$groupid' AND `ts` + INTERVAL 7 DAY < NOW() ORDER BY ts LIMIT 1 ");
$ts=mysql_fetch_array($tsquery);

if(isset($ts)){
echo "<img src='images/care.png' title='Care Group' style='border: none; background-color:     #fff;'>";
} else {
}
```

I'm getting false results on some people.  If someone didn't attend an event 2 weeks ago, but did attend an event yesterday, it's returning true rather than finding that they were in attendance within the last two weeks.   Is there a better way of doing this that would return more accurate results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to turn your logic around a bit. Checking for the presence of rows matching `ts + INTERVAL 7 DAY < NOW()` means "did they attend any events *more* than 7 days ago"? Checking for rows matching `ts + INTERVAL 7 DAY >= NOW()` means "did they attend any events in the past week?" If there are *no* rows then they haven't done anything in a week.

(Also, just a nitpick, but you have "two weeks" in prose and "7 days" in code. Two weeks is, of course, 14 days.)

Comment: Isn't `$ts` an associate array, not the value of ts as well? Or does PHP return null for an associate array if there is no rows in the result? Just an additional problem I thought maybe. I am not super familiar with mysql query functions in PHP.

Comment: @thatidiotguy good question. The docs say that `mysql_fetch_array` returns false for zero rows, not an empty array. So `isset` is probably the wrong test, but `if (!$ts)` would work fine.

Comment: Thank you hobbs!  I'm still new to MySQL so sometimes I just need to be pointed in the right direction.  It seems to be working perfectly now.